# Subtracting previous row minus current row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a table `orders`.

How do I subtract previous row minus current row for the column `Incoming`?

[image]

Comment: What defined previous row ? date ? and what would be your expected result from the given sample data ? And is it for mysql or oracle ?

Comment: try to use lead oracle function :)

Comment: Hi Abhik, I need it for column incoming

Comment: Why the PL/SQL tag? Do you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in My SQL

```
 select a.Incoming, 
coalesce(a.Incoming - 
    (select b.Incoming from orders b where b.id = a.id + 1), a.Incoming) as differance
from orders a
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function in Oracle.

Try this query

```
SELECT DATE_IN,Incoming,
   LAG(Incoming, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Incoming) AS inc_previous,
   LAG(Incoming, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Incoming) - Incoming AS Diff
FROM orders
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbab6/1)

Comment: order by Incoming is not correct. subtract _previous_ row minus current row, not the difference to the next row was requested. So I think, right direction, wrong answer? :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
create table orders (date_in date, incoming_vol number);

insert into orders values (to_date('27.05.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 83);
insert into orders values (to_date('26.05.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 107);
insert into orders values (to_date('25.05.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 20);
insert into orders values (to_date('24.05.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 7);
insert into orders values (to_date('22.05.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 71);
```

The LAG function is used to access data from a previous row

```
SELECT DATE_IN,
       incoming_vol as incoming,
       LAG(incoming_vol, 1, incoming_vol) OVER (ORDER BY date_in) - incoming_vol AS incoming_diff
FROM orders
order by 1 desc
```

Another solution without analytical functions:

```
select o.date_in, o.incoming_vol, p.incoming_vol-o.incoming_vol
from orders p, orders o
where p.date_in = (select nvl(max(oo.date_in), o.date_in) 
                   from orders oo where oo.date_in < o.date_in)
;
```

Comment: thanks you are a life saver. Was struggling with this